# Magento dashboard after login to admin panel shows dashboard page with broken images and contents

Tags: magento

I installed Magento on my local window and when i opened its dashboard after login to admin panel it shows dashboard page with broken images and contents.
Here is the screen shot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0iGE.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too old, and is rather related to https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I Just solved this way, after having changed my language locale for my admin account in one not installed (it_IT, thus I could not go back to original en_US because of no link functionality.

Follow these rules:

1) find your directory `pub\static\adminhtml\Magento\backend\en_US` (or original install package in your case)

2) copy all content in the other `\backend` directory, overwriting all.

3) refresh browser.

Answer (score 0):

Run commands for static-content deploy & Indexing in the cmd.
1. /bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
2. /bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. /bin/magento cache:clean
4. /bin/magento cache:flush